# Parting lines based on intersection with polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two tables:

1. `roads` containing one row (line) for each road with column `road_code` uniquely identifying the name of the road;
2. `districts` containing one row (polygon) for each district with column `district_code` uniquely identifying each district.

I want to create a new table of lines called `roads_by_district`, where each road from the table `roads` is parted based on the intersection with the `districts`.

So table `roads_by_district` should look like

```
road_code | district_code | geom(line)
H1          District_A      0105...
H2          District_A      0105...
H1          District_B      0105...
H2          District_B      0105...
```

I guess I should use a query with `ST_Intersects` and `ST_Contains` but I don't want to return the entire road `H1` that partially intersects with district `District_A`, but only the part of `H1` that is totally contained by `District_A`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my query:

```
CREATE TABLE roads_by_district AS
SELECT a.road_id as road_id, a.comune_id as comune_id,
       ST_Intersection(a.geomline, a.geompoly) as geom
FROM (SELECT roads.road_code as road_id, comuni.pro_com As comune_id,
             roads.geom as geomline, districts.geom as geompoly
       FROM roads INNER JOIN districts
       ON (ST_Intersects(roads.geom, districts.geom, 4326))) a;
```